# Cygwin linking NASM 64 dll to C library using ld

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, nasm

Using Cygwin, I need to link a 64-bit NASM dll to the C library.  I compile with NASM and link with gcc's ld.  However, ld reports that it cannot find the C library, no matter what I try.

The NASM compile string is:

```
nasm -f elf64 Cyg64_01.asm
```

The ld linker string is:

```
ld Cyg64_01.o -l cygwin1.dll -o Cyg64_01.so --verbose
```

Using just cygwin1, not cygwin1.dll, gives the same result.

The Cygwin manual says that its C library is newlib, but linking to newlib doesn't work.  An earlier post on Stack Overflow says:  "The C library on Cygwin is cygwin1.dll (part of the cygwin package), which is based on newlib" so I am using cygwin1.dll, located in Cygwin64\bin.

Using the verbose option, I see that Cygwin does not search Cygwin64\bin\ for libraries, but if I include the full path it still doesn't find it.

In the "Mapping Path Names" section of the Cygwin manual, it says that new paths are added to the Cygwin Mount Table; using the linux mount command, I see that Cygwin64\bin\ is already in the mount table.

My question is:  (1) am I linking to the right C library (for an assembler program, not a C or C++ program), and (2) do I need to reference the path differently?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First off Cygwin generates native files for Windows. Shared objects are usually named with a `.dll` extension on Windows (not .so). You can link with something like `gcc -shared -lcygwin Cyg64_01.o -o Cyg64_01.dll` . Among other things it is `-lcygwin` to link with the cygwin dll

Comment: I am using Cygwin to get debug symbols, which I cannot get for Windows -- .pdb format is not documented, so no non-msoft compiler will output them.  If I get native Windows files, will I get debug symbols that I can use with GCC's GDB?  And yes, the file name is Cyg64_01.o; I just edited the question to correct that.

Comment: Your suggested compile string does output a dll; I notice that it's 134K in size, which is much larger than the 5K object file; that seems very large compared to Windows dlls I have created -- any thoughts?

Comment: it outputs a `dll` if you use `-shared`. You can tell if you run the command `file Cyg64_01.dll` after. It should say `Cyg64_01.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows` . Yes, it is larger. It has padding, headers, code. The DLL will be larger than the `.o`  file.

Comment: You can strip it of the excess including the debug info with `strip Cyg64_01.dll`

Comment: The size isn't an issue, really -- it's just larger compared to the .o than Windows dlls I have created.  I am now trying gdb with dwarf symbols.